# Understanding the isomorphisms and direct sums in Structure Theorem proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, modules

**Background:**

SNF Consequence: Given $M$, a submodule of $R^n$, there exists elements $d_1,...,d_r$ and $f_1,...,f_n$ where $f_i$ forms a basis for $R^n$ such that $d_1f_1,..,d_rf_r$ forms a basis for $M$ and $d_1|d_2|...|d_r.$

**Structure Theorem:** Let M be a finitely generated $R$- module then $\exists d_1,...,d_k$ such that $M\cong R^r\bigoplus\frac{R}{\langle d_1\rangle}\bigoplus...\bigoplus\frac{R}{\langle d_k\rangle}$ and $d_1|d_2|...|d_k$.

**Proof:** Suppose $M$ is generated by $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ then there exists a surjective module homorphism such that $\phi:R^n\to M$. By First Isomorphism Theorem, we have $\frac{R^n}{\ker\phi}\cong M$. Now since $\ker\phi$ is a submodule of $M$ we can apply SNF Conseq. from above, $$M\cong\frac{\langle f_1,..,f_n\rangle}{\langle d_1f_1,...d_kf_k\rangle}\cong\frac{\langle f_1\rangle}{\langle d_1f_1\rangle}\bigoplus...\bigoplus \frac{\langle f_k\rangle}{\langle d_kf_k\rangle}\bigoplus\langle f_{k+1}\rangle\bigoplus...\bigoplus\langle f_n\rangle.$$Now $\frac{\langle f_i\rangle}{\langle d_if_i\rangle}\cong\frac{R}{\langle d_i\rangle}$ and ${\langle f_{k+1}\rangle}\cong R$ and similarly for other summands, we have the required result.

**My Problem with this proof:**

I wanted to know more details that go into this $$M\cong\frac{\langle f_1,..,f_n\rangle}{\langle d_1f_1,...d_kf_k\rangle}\cong\frac{\langle f_1\rangle}{\langle d_1f_1\rangle}\bigoplus...\bigoplus \frac{\langle f_k\rangle}{\langle d_kf_k\rangle}\bigoplus\langle f_{k+1}\rangle\bigoplus...\bigoplus\langle f_n\rangle.$$

Does this stand because $$M\cong\frac{\langle f_1,..,f_n\rangle}{\langle d_1f_1,...d_kf_k\rangle}\cong \frac{\langle f_1\rangle}{\langle d_1f_1,..d_kf_k\rangle}\bigoplus...\bigoplus \frac{\langle f_n\rangle}{\langle d_1f_1,...,d_kf_k\rangle}.$$ But how would this lead to the aforementioned result? (I have a feeling this will have something to do with the basis but I cannot seem to explain rigorously in my head)

Moreover, I am not convinced that ${\langle f_{k+1}\rangle}\cong R$ is necessarily true, why would this have to stand? (i.e., I am not convinced that if $n$ elements generate $R^n$ then each element must generate $R$).

Many thanks in advance and I really would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this stand because
>   $M≅\frac{⟨f_1,..,f_n⟩}{⟨d_1f_1,...,d_kf_k⟩}≅\frac{⟨f_1⟩}{⟨d_1f_1,...,d_kf_k⟩}⨁...⨁\frac{⟨f_n⟩}{⟨d_1f_1,...,d_kf_k⟩}$?

This is not quite correct as written, because quotients on the RHS cannot be taken as the denominators are not submodules of the numerators.

If you want an explicit isomorphism 
$$\frac{\langle f_1,...,f_n\rangle}{\langle d_1f_1,...,d_kf_k\rangle}\cong\frac{\langle f_1\rangle}{\langle d_1f_1\rangle}\bigoplus...\bigoplus \frac{\langle f_k\rangle}{\langle d_kf_k\rangle}\bigoplus\langle f_{k+1}\rangle\bigoplus...\bigoplus\langle f_n\rangle,$$ you should map $\lambda_1 f_1 + \cdots \lambda_n f_n \mapsto (\lambda_1 f_1, \cdots, \lambda_n f_n)$. This is well defined, because the $f_i$ form a basis of $M$.

---

> Now $\frac{⟨f_i⟩}{⟨d_if_i⟩}≅R⟨d_i⟩$ and $⟨d_{k+1}⟩≅R$ and similarly for other summands, we have the required result.

I think you wanted to say $⟨f_{k+1}⟩≅R$. This is true since the elements of $⟨f_{k+1}⟩$ are just scalar multiples of $f_{k+1}$.

Comment: I agree with 'the elements of $⟨f_{k+1}⟩$ are just scalar multiples of $f_{k+1}$' but why would that suggest it will be congruent to $R$?

Comment: The isomorphism is $\langle f_{k+1} \rangle \to R$ given by $rf_{k+1} \mapsto r$.

Comment: Thanks, I had a good think about your map here, if we have $R$ as a unital ring, would that necessarily imply $f_{k+1},...,f_n$ are all units of $R$?

Comment: No problem. The reason why this may seem strange is that while $R$ is a ring, it is also an $R$-module and we treat it as such. In particular, the map above has nothing to do with rings, it is an $R$-module isomorphism. The elements $f_{i}$ are elements of $M$ and the don't belong to $R$.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, I had an issue with understanding $\lambda_1 f_1 + \cdots \lambda_n f_n \mapsto (\lambda_1 f_1, \cdots, \lambda_n f_n)$. Why would this map imply the first summand is $\frac{\langle f_1\rangle}{\langle d_1f_1\rangle}$ rather than, say, $\langle d_1\rangle$?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Carefully think about what set each element belongs to. $M$ is a module and $f_i$ are its elements that form a basis. This means that we can take elements $d_i \in R$ and form linear combinations of these basis elements, such as $d_1f_1$ or $f_7+d_8f_{11}$. We can take some of them and consider submodules such as $\langle d_1 f_1, f_7+d_8f_{11} \rangle$ and we can take quotients. But an expression such as $\langle d_1 \rangle$ doesn't make sense, because this is not a submodule of $M$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say $\langle f_1\rangle$ rather than $\langle d_1\rangle$. I guess what I am trying to ask is that how does $\frac{\langle f_1\rangle}{\langle f_1d_1\rangle}$ come to our discussion via the map you gave previously? (apologies for making this rather complicated)

Comment: I believe this $\lambda_1 f_1 + \cdots \lambda_n f_n \mapsto (\lambda_1 f_1, \cdots, \lambda_n f_n)$ is the map we are talking about. If $M$ is not free (that is, if $d_1 \neq 0$), then it cannot have a non-trivial map to $\langle f_1 \rangle$ which is free. To make things more concrete, take $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $M=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. What I said in the previous sentence is that there is no non-trivial map $M \to \mathbb{Z}= \langle f_1 \rangle$. So it is necessary to impose the condition $6f_1 =0$ in the image.